# Does controllerAs work with Isolated Scope?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

I'm familiar with using controllerAs, but do not understand why, when using with isolated scope, none of my controller properties are showing up on the scope.

Here's a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/7c3gZFHTmjMqspAnmu8g) showing what I'm talking about.

Why is `vm.min` and `vm.max` both blank when I specifically set properties from within the controller function?

If I remove the isolate scope, `{{vm.min}}` works, as expected.  But with the isolated scope, it does not.

**1)** `this.min` was set within the `controller`, so `{{vm.min}}` should have a value, right?
**2)** the property `max` was set on the element, so when i use `bindToController` and the isolated scope, `{{max}}` should have a value, right?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have taken the vm.min and vm.max inside the `my-example directive`, it did not work for you.

Check this code once,

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function myExample() {
  var directive = {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {
      max: '='
    },
    controller: ExampleController,
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    bindToController: true, // because the scope is isolated,
    templateUrl: `tpl.html`
  };
  return directive;
}

ExampleController.$inject = ['$scope'];

function ExampleController($scope) {
  // Injecting $scope just for comparison
  var vm = this;
  vm.min = 3;
}

angular
  .module('myApp')
  .directive('myExample', myExample);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.5.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Why are vm.min and vm.max both blank?</h1>
    <my-example max="5">
      
    </my-example>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="tpl.html">
    <div>
        vm.min: {{vm.min}}
        <br/>
        vm.max: {{vm.max}}
      </div>
  </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

If you want to use the templates inside the directive, you should use `transclude` option.

Comment: @Augie Gardner, pls accept the answer if you find helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `template` or `templateUrl` attribute in which those values need to be rendered.